# Environment variables in database.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have added DB credentials as environment variables (using nginx), so that i can use them like so:

```
return array(

    'connections' => array(

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'mysql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => getenv('DB_NAME'),
            'username' => getenv('DB_USER'),
            'password' => getenv('DB_PASS'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            )

    )
);
```

The problem is that when I use artisan the environment variables do not seem to be available, so when i run migrate or seed i get errors.

Is there a way around that or should i just write my DB credentials directly in my config file ?

Comment: as far as I know artisan is run as a CLI script, check to see if those ENV variables are available in CLI mode

Comment: @cecilozaur Yeah actually they are created by the web server so that make sense that aren't in CLI mode,Bummer :(

Answer (score 0):

To edit my previous answer (sorry for misunderstandig):

Yes, environment variables are created by server, so they can't be reached or modified from CLI. Before deploying, server is generating those variables, so they can be "injected" into application at runtime.
I am thinking that it is maybe possible to reach those variables through **remote** Laravel package and SSH ? For example **php artisan tail** command is reading locally errors from the server side.

Comment: This is not relevant for my question, environment variables are just not available in CLI mode..